# How to upgrade from Magento 2.3.1 CE to Magento 2.*.* EE?

Tags: upgrade, installation, docker, magento-enterprise-2

I am trying to upgrade from community edition to enterprise edition. I have access keys for EE. I am using [this](https://github.com/rhinos-dubai/docker-magento2) docker image for magento 2.

**P.S:** As I do not have docker image for M2 EE so I am trying to upgrade CE after installing.

After installing M2 CE I am doing this:

1. Updated access keys in auth.json file
2. Edited Composer.json file From(Orignal one):

   ```
   {
   "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
   "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
   "type": "project",
   "license": [
   "OSL-3.0",
   "AFL-3.0"
   ],
   "config": {
   "preferred-install": "dist",
   "sort-packages": true
   },
   "require": {
   "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.1"
   },
   "require-dev": {
   "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.13.0",
   "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
   "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "~2.3.13",
   "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
   "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
   "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
   "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
   "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.3.1",
   "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0"
   },
   "conflict": {
   "gene/bluefoot": "*"
   },
   "autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
       "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
       "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
       "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
       "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
   },
   "psr-0": {
       "": [
           "app/code/",
           "generated/code/"
       ]
   },
   "files": [
       "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
   ],
   "exclude-from-classmap": [
       "**/dev/**",
       "**/update/**",
       "**/Test/**"
   ]
    },
   "autoload-dev": {
   "psr-4": {
       "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
       "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
       "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
       "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
       "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
   }
   },
   "version": "2.3.1",
   "minimum-stability": "stable",
   "repositories": [
   {
       "type": "composer",
       "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
   }
   ],
   "extra": {
   "magento-force": "override"
   }
   }
   ```

To (Changed name, type, license and "require")

```
    {
    "name": "magento/product-enterprise-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Enterprise Edition)",
    "type": "metapakage",
    "license": [
    "Proprietary"
    ],
    "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
    },
    "require": {
    "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.3.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.13.0",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
    "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "~2.3.13",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.3.1",
    "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
    "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": [
            "app/code/",
            "generated/code/"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "**/dev/**",
        "**/update/**",
        "**/Test/**"
    ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": 
    "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
    },
    "version": "2.3.1",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    }
    ],
    "extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
    }
    }
```

And after this, executed command,

> composer update

but it removed so many dependencies e.g:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 5 installs, 24 updates, 309 removals
  - Removing zendframework/zend-view (2.10.1)
Removing Zendframework/ZendView
  - Removing zendframework/zend-validator (2.11.1)
Removing Zendframework/ZendValidator
  - Removing zendframework/zend-uri (2.7.0)
Removing Zendframework/ZendUri
  - Removing zendframework/zend-text (2.7.0)
Removing Zendframework/ZendText
.............................
.............................

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MagentoHackathon\Composer\Magento\MapParser' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento-composer-installer/src/MagentoHackathon/Composer/Magento/Installer.php:758
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento-composer-installer/src/MagentoHackathon/Composer/Magento/Installer.php(724): MagentoHackathon\Composer\Magento\Installer->getParser(Object(Composer\Package\CompletePackage))
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php(211): MagentoHackathon\Composer\Magento\Installer->uninstall(Object(Composer\Repository\InstalledFilesystemRepository), Object(Composer\Package\CompletePackage))
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php(160): Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->uninstall(Object(Composer\Repository\InstalledFilesystemRepository), Object(Composer\DependencyResolver\Operation\UninstallOperation))
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php(595): Composer\Installer\InstallationM in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento-composer-installer/src/MagentoHackathon/Composer/Magento/Installer.php on line 758
```

I am trying for long time. If you have some idea are know how to install EE and run as docker image, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: any solution on this?

Comment: @Devidas yes, just updated CE to EE with "System Upgrade" option available in backend. System > Tool > Web Setup Wizard

Comment: There all community third party modules is work or not aftter upgrade CE to EE

Comment: Everything which is working on CE will also work on EE

Comment: In my CE I use marketplace extension with developing most of the Rest API so it's working or not In EE ?

Comment: Technically it should work. May be some improvements in code you need to do due to version change. In my case, everything was fine after the upgrade.

Comment: thank you very much for your help @Ajwad Syed

Answer (score 1):

Just upgraded CE to EE with "**System Upgrade**" option available in the backend.

> System > Tools > Web Setup Wizard

Comment: is this only one way to upgrade?

Comment: yes, there are other ways. I followed this one.

Comment: which another way you followd

Answer (score 0):

You can directly upgrade from CE to EE from Magento admin with '**System upgrade**', following all steps in this dev doc: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/upgrader/ce-ee-upgrade-start.html

However, after the upgrading process, you may find several **unpredictable issues**. Besides, Magento announced that the **Web Setup Wizard is being deprecated in Magento 2.3.6 and will be removed in Magento 2.4.0**, so you should find another way.

I think you should try to find the Magento migration expert to help you perform the Magento CE to EE upgrade securely and accurately!