# Magento is not supported on Windows OS and Mac OS?

Tags: upgrade, docker, windows, ubuntu, macbook

I'm trying to upgrade from community edition of Magento 2.3.1 to Enetreprise Edition of M2. I am using docker Image for M2 CE and trying to upgrade to M2 EE.

I have tried below ways:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278212/upgrade-from-open-source-to-commerce-magento-2
- [How to upgrade from Magento 2.3.1 CE to Magento 2.*.* EE?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278139/how-to-upgrade-from-magento-2-3-1-ce-to-magento-2-ee)

but no luck yet.

Still trying and came across this link:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Here a statement is: Operating systems (Linux x86-64)
Linux distributions, such as RedHat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), CentOS, Ubuntu, Debian, and similar.

**Magento is not supported on:
Windows OS,
Mac OS**

I didn't get this point, can somebody clarify this.. As I know Magento works on MAC OS and Windows. Is there any stack requirement that Magento is not upgrading to Enterprise Edition ?

Comment: Check the php and mysql version. Working fine with Mac OS.

Comment: Yes with Docker image of M2 CE working fine..

Answer (score 2):

it can be installed anywhere where you can run LAMP stack.
support and not working is different.

Answer (score 0):

That's the point in docker. The stack inside the container (or more accurately built up of several containers) will outcome the same regardless of which OS is used.

That's the main reason why devs use docker. You can build an identical stack to co workers in minutes.

The only difference I've encountered is performance. As soon as you start mounting folders so that you can edit files in the container outside of the container linux leads the way.

Also you can encounter permission issues.

It's crazy but the best setup on windows for me so far is to run ubuntu minimal on hyper-v. Run docker in ubuntu VM. This is faster than running natively in windows.