# Upgrade from Open Source to Commerce Error

Tags: magento-enterprise, upgrade, installation

- I am [upgrading](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/upgrader/ce-ee-upgrade-start.html) Magento 2.3.1 Community Edition to Magento 2.3.1 Enterprise Edition.
- All [these](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq_compman.html) prerequisites are done ✅
- By Upgrade from the [Magento Admin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/upgrader/ce-ee-upgrade-start.html#compman-access) it do not give option of Eneterprise Edition in the list, it is only CE.
- By following [Command line](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html) Upgrade, it stucks when I execute:

  ```
  composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.3.2 --no-update
  ```

  and prompts this error message:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Could not find a matching version of package
>   magento/product-enterprise-edition. Check the package spelling, your
>   version con     straint and that the package is available in a
>   stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).

The issue is not getting solved by many developers like me. Need your kind attention !

Comment: do you have your correct credentials in your ~/.composer/auth.json ?

Comment: have you tried change the composer.json manually and then running composer update?

Comment: Yes, I tried by changing composer.json. This is how I edited it. Pls see to verify changes are correct or not. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278139/how-to-upgrade-from-magento-2-3-1-ce-to-magento-2-ee

Comment: you should never, EVER post your access keys public!!!!

Comment: these keys on github are for community edition dear..

Comment: you shouldn't even do this